"But he was also an artist" in Oscar Wilde's "The Model Millionaire"
The following lines are an extract from the short-story "The Model Millionaire" by Oscar Wilde

Trevor was a painter. But he was also an artist, and artists are rather rare.

I think painters are considered as artists. Why is it mentioned separately? I want an explanation of this line.

Wilde is playing with two senses of “artist”. If you look at any dictionary, you should find these (or equivalent) senses:


A person who creates art.

A person who is skilled at some activity.


Wiktionary.

A reader of ‘The Model Millionaire’ might start by interpreting “artist” in sense 1, that is, anyone who creates art. But that doesn’t make sense in light of “artists are rather rare”. So the narrator must be using the word in sense 2, a person who is skilled at painting. The sentence is thus an arch comment on the rarity of skill in painters.

Or 'a person who paints with creative imagination rather than just technical skill'.

Yes, there are different ways in which someone could be considered to be "skilled".
